# Why are "wmic diskdrive get size" and "(Get-Disk).Size" returning slightly different values?

Tags: powershell, disk-space-utilization, diskmanagement, wmic

As you can see, the following commands provide slightly different output. Why? I was expecting them to be the same. There is a 2.66MB difference between the two.

***How can I get the values from "wmic diskdrive get size" in powershell?*** This is the value I'm needing and it's the one that appears in the MSINFO32 tool.

- wmic diskdrive get size
- (Get-Disk).Size
- (Get-PhysicalDisk).Size

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> wmic diskdrive get size
Size          

858990666240  
103079208960  

PS C:\Windows\system32> (Get-Disk).Size
858993459200
103079215104

PS C:\Windows\system32> (Get-PhysicalDisk).Size
858993459200
103079215104
```

Comment: `wmic diskdrive get size` is _unformatted_ capacity, see `Get-CimInstance Win32_DiskDrive | Select-Object -Property SerialNumber, Size, @{ name='CountSize'; expr={$_.TotalCylinders * $_.TracksPerCylinder * $_.SectorsPerTrack * $_.BytesPerSector} }`.  Check `Get-Disk|select UniqueID,AllocatedSize,Size` and `Get-Partition|select UniqueId, Offset, Size` as well… BTW, this _2.66MB difference_ is roughly `0.000325` percent…